# showing camera capture image to gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, camera, bitmapimage

I am developing an app in which, i click image using camera and show it into an grid view. but my image not showing in image view without showing any error. but when i debug the project i notice that, my array list is empty. i don't understand exactly where my code going wrong.

**here is my code :**

```
 /* private GridView gvGallery;*/

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
              bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
              byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            imageArry.add(new Contact(byteArray));
            cameraAdapter = new CameraAdapter(this, R.layout.gv_item, imageArry);
            gvGallery.setAdapter(cameraAdapter);
            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
            gvGallery.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + imageArry.size());
            }
  }
```

**My Adapter Class:**

```
private class CameraAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
// BcardImage data[] = null;
ArrayList<Contact> data;

CameraAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ImageHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Contact picture = data.get(position);
    //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class
    byte[] outImage=picture._image;
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
    return row;
}

class ImageHolder
{   ImageView imgIcon; }
```

}

**contact class:**

```
private static class Contact {
    byte[] _image;
    // Empty constructor
    public Contact() { }
    public Contact(byte[] _image) {
        this._image = _image;
    }
    public byte[] get_image() {
        return _image;
    }
    public void set_image(byte[] _image) {
        this._image = _image;
    }
}
```

**and here is my xml file for button and gridview :**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:text="@string/Camera"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Gallery"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            tools:ignore="NotSibling,UnknownId" />

    </RelativeLayout>

       <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gv"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </GridView>

     </RelativeLayout>

**and another gv_item.XML file for imageview :**

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGallery"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I notice your image array is empty so only you are not seeing any image. First add the image before passing array to adapter.

```
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
cameraAdapter = new CameraAdapter(this, R.layout.gv_item, imageArry);
```

You can see from above code imageArry is empty and does not contain anything

Add data to imageArry using `imageArray.add(Contact)` like shown below

```
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
imageArray.add(new Contact(Add your data as per model class))
 cameraAdapter = new CameraAdapter(this, R.layout.gv_item, imageArry);
```

Once you add you should possibly see the data. Hope this helps.

Comment: it saying create field 'contact'  in MainActivity

Comment: You have to add new Contact object

Comment: okay. now i get image in grid view but when i trying to add new image it replace old one

Comment: how are you trying to add new one? With the current code you can add only one image, you have to maintain separate list to add multiple items

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it as Answer

Comment: @BlackCoder how you add multiple images without replacing the older one ?

Comment: You maintain a list out the onActivityResult. Initialize the list as a class variable means
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>(); add this line after class definition when you declare your variables. That should make you add multiple images

Comment: omg...i am so stupid. thanks for the help <3 <3. can you comment or answer in my question so that i can accept it as answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039248/displaying-multiple-camera-images-to-grid-view this my quetion link

Answer (score 0):

I will slightly change the answer Keshav1234. change adapter constructor like this:

```
private class CameraAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<>();

public CameraAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setData(Contact contact){
    data.add(contact);
}
//...
}
```

and after you get the object Contact, call this method inside your activity/fragment

```
adapter.setContact(Contact);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As a result, your list will increase

Comment: after adding this, my app crash without showing any error :(

Comment: o no). i am sorry. please delete this line in constructor of adapter : " ... super(context, layoutResourceId, data);..." forgot to delete this line. of course the problem is this

Comment: @droidbaza i have the same problem and i used your code but nothing work

Comment: see my quetion     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039248/displaying-multiple-camera-images-to-grid-view