# Displaying multiple camera images to Grid view

Tags: java, android-studio, gridview, camera, android-imageview

i want to display multiple images capture by camera to Grid view. i go through many questions how to do but non perfectly work for me. i use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985137/showing-camera-capture-image-to-gridview) to implement. but using this i am able to get the image in my image view but whenever i capture new image that image replace my older image. and now i am clue less what should i do to add camera images one after another. anyone know how to implement this then please help me with sample code. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the comment provided in the answer in this link:

[showing camera capture image to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985137/showing-camera-capture-image-to-gridview)

This should serve your purpose. Hope this helps. Let me know if you face any issues

You maintain a list out the onActivityResult. Initialize the list as a class variable means

```
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

add this line after class definition when you declare your variables. That should make you add multiple images